# PHP - Grabbing every 4th value from serialized data

Tags: php

I have a script that takes a number of filenames, and then serializes the data, there can be hundreds of filenames in the serialized data.

What i want to be able to do is echo out every 4th filename.

Im not quite sure how to go about this, if someone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

The following is an example of the serialized data, its only got 8 records, so only 2 filenames would be output

```
a:8:{i:0;s:62:"1328018910RYw4LKmf3yb2ZhCHcFB9VvPqGMTrxgXzdDpWQntJN7k6j8_o.jpg";i:1;s:62:"1328018910RYw4LKmf3yb2ZhCHcFB9VvPqGMTrxgXzdDpWQntJN7k6j8_s.jpg";i:2;s:62:"1328018910RYw4LKmf3yb2ZhCHcFB9VvPqGMTrxgXzdDpWQntJN7k6j8_t.jpg";i:3;s:63:"1328018910RYw4LKmf3yb2ZhCHcFB9VvPqGMTrxgXzdDpWQntJN7k6j8_st.jpg";i:4;s:62:"1328018917rdwfFQ3xBDgvLKZCH4j8qTpYkz2VmJ9y7XntRcNbMG6PWh_o.jpg";i:5;s:62:"1328018917rdwfFQ3xBDgvLKZCH4j8qTpYkz2VmJ9y7XntRcNbMG6PWh_s.jpg";i:6;s:62:"1328018917rdwfFQ3xBDgvLKZCH4j8qTpYkz2VmJ9y7XntRcNbMG6PWh_t.jpg";i:7;s:63:"1328018917rdwfFQ3xBDgvLKZCH4j8qTpYkz2VmJ9y7XntRcNbMG6PWh_st.jpg";}
```

Comment: What's the problem with `unserialize`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with the MOD operator or a simple for loop:

```
$data = "a:8:{i:0;s:62:"1328018910RYw4LKmf3yb2ZhCHcFB9VvPqGMTrxgXzdDpWQntJN7k6j8_o.jpg";i:1;s:62:"1328018910RYw4LKmf3yb2ZhCHcFB9VvPqGMTrxgXzdDpWQntJN7k6j8_s.jpg";i:2;s:62:"1328018910RYw4LKmf3yb2ZhCHcFB9VvPqGMTrxgXzdDpWQntJN7k6j8_t.jpg";i:3;s:63:"1328018910RYw4LKmf3yb2ZhCHcFB9VvPqGMTrxgXzdDpWQntJN7k6j8_st.jpg";i:4;s:62:"1328018917rdwfFQ3xBDgvLKZCH4j8qTpYkz2VmJ9y7XntRcNbMG6PWh_o.jpg";i:5;s:62:"1328018917rdwfFQ3xBDgvLKZCH4j8qTpYkz2VmJ9y7XntRcNbMG6PWh_s.jpg";i:6;s:62:"1328018917rdwfFQ3xBDgvLKZCH4j8qTpYkz2VmJ9y7XntRcNbMG6PWh_t.jpg";i:7;s:63:"1328018917rdwfFQ3xBDgvLKZCH4j8qTpYkz2VmJ9y7XntRcNbMG6PWh_st.jpg";}"

$data = unserialize($data);
for($idata = 3; $idata <= count($data)-1; $idata += 4){
    echo $data[$idata].'<br />';
}
```

If you want the mod operator do this instead:

```
$data = unserialize($data);
$idata = 0;
foreach($data as $dataitem){
    if(($idata % 4) == 3){
        echo $dataitem.'<br />';
    }
}
```

Modulo is an operator that divides a number by X and returns the remainder:

```
0 % 4 = 0
1 % 4 = 1
2 % 4 = 2
3 % 4 = 3
4 % 4 = 0
5 % 4 = 1
6 % 4 = 2
7 % 4 = 3
8 % 4 = 0
9 % 4 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply Serialize the returned data ... then you can catch